# AC Generator for maximum load

Tags: generator

I just bought a Honda Generator Model# EG 6500CL, with the setting on 110V only, I want to deliver the maximum rated current of 45.8V to one load.  There are 3 receptacles available, 2 at 20A, 1 at 30A and all the outputs are in phase and from the same winding.  The Operation Manual states you cannot exceed receptacle current limits. Can I parallel 2 or 3 receptacles to achieve the maximum current rating of 45.8A? Honda Canada would not give a definitive answer.

Comment: This site is not for providing directions explaining how to use products. I am voting to close the question. Connecting receptacles in parallel will not assure that the current will be properly divided among the receptacles. Parallel operation is not a proper use of the receptacles and will invalidate the UL listing. The circuit breakers will probably prevent damage, but that does not mean that what you propose is proper use.

Comment: Yes you could run into trouble if they have different fuse protection values.  But if there is only a common Circuit breaker it may be ok. ... as long as you construct the branch cable correctly and keep short or use AWG to minimize losses with suitable endpoint connection.

Comment: If you parallel two circuits then if you unplug one lead its pins will be live and not touch-proof. Bad idea for this and the other reasons listed.

Comment: @Transistor You added something essential. I wrote about it in my answer. Unfortunately nothing stops some people as long as they stay alive. I have seen custom 230VAC extension cords where a male plug is in both ends.

Answer (score 4):

Don't do it! As commented already, the current can be too non-uniformly distributed due different resistances. In addition:

- Have you already checked that the outputs really come from the same winding (=in parallel connected windings) in the single voltage mode? The actual generator in the machine must be extremely precisely made if there's parallel windings.
- If yes, then how you can be sure that all output connectors to your single load stay connected and none is ever reversed?
- Have you checked what happens if the machine is in 2 voltage mode and the outputs still are in parallel?

If one or two pops out or get damaged, something can get overheated without warning. Reversing = Short circuit.

The manufacturer would never allow your planned connection because they should pay your burned house if they allowed the connection and you left 2 outputs disconnected.

**User Transistor had added something essential**: Unplugged parallel connector has full voltage. => If the manufacturer allowed your connection, they should also prepare to pay the possible funerals.

Comment: It sounds like there are too many variables trying to combine the the different maximum outputs. I could overload the output of one or more receptacles. The Operational Manual does have a schematic drawing showing a common winding with the 3 receptacles in parallel. I will divide the load to keep the output of the 3 receptacles within current limits.